# Replacing all the hyphens in xml tags with underscore using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Suppose I've a string containing the XML output as follows:

```
<dept-details>
     <dept-domain-id>1</dept-domain-id>
     <dept-req-status>no-vacancies-present</dept-req-status>
      .
      .
</dept-details>
```

I want to replace all the tags containing hyphen(-) with underscore(_) as I see that Beautiful Soup doesn't let you directly access tags containing - except by using find() as [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beautifulsoup/jhg9j-tNlvk) post says and so do [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beautifulsoup/0XTGsVXy5bw).

So my intention is to convert the tags containing - to _  so that the string looks like:

```
<dept_details>
     <dept_domain_id>1</dept_domain_id>
     <dept_req_status>no-vacancies-present</dept_req_status>
      .
      .
</dept_details>
```

I wanted to know how can I use python re methods to achieve this or if I can do it with BeautifulSoup directly that would be great!

Thanks in advance

Comment: BeautifulSoup is great for HTML, not so great for XML.

Comment: [etree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is better suited for xml parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need regular expressions here, try this solution:

```
>>> s
'<dept-details><dept-domain-id>1</dept-domain-id><dept-req-status>no-vacancies</dept-req-status></dept-details>'
>>> re.sub('<(.*?)>', lambda x: x.group(0).replace('-','_'), s)
'<dept_details><dept_domain_id>1</dept_domain_id><dept_req_status>no-vacancies</dept_req_status></dept_details>'
```

There are some issues with the regular expression, for example it will also replace any attributes that have `-`, but at least this will get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: See Burhan's answer, it is much better.

```
string = '<dept-details><dept-domain-id>1</dept-domain-id><dept-req-status>no-vacancies-present</dept-req-status></dept-details>'

import re

tags = re.finditer('<.*?-.*?>', string)

for x in tags:
    string = string[:x.span()[0]] + x.group(0).replace('-','_') + string[x.span()[1]:]

print string
```

Where string is your actual XML code string. There is definitely a better way though.